# Regex starting from phrase to end of doc with condition

Tags: python, regex

I have a starting phrase say `fruits`. I have some ending phrase like `apple` , `banana` and `pineapple`.

I have some documents with variable as `text`:

1. > Fruits
   >
   > They are good for health....
   >
   > should eat Apple
2. > Fruits
   >
   > eat regularly banana
   >
   > Fruits you  need
   >
   > to eat Apple
3. > Fruits are good
   >
   > Daily we should have pineapple
   >
   > In general, fruits have various minerals.
   >
   > Most of them are very tasty

**My Regex and code:**

```
p = r'(\bFruits\b\s*\w*\s*\n*.*?(\bApples?\b|\bbananas?\b|\bpineapples?\b))'
sep = ";;"
lst = re.findall(p, text, re.I|re.M|re.DOTALL)
val = sep.join(str(v) for v in lst )
```

Above regex works well in `text` 1 & 2 and partially in `text` 3.

**Problem**:

All I need is when we encounter fruit and don't find any of the ending phrase, then and only then go till end of document.

**Expected Output from** `text` **3**:

```
Fruits are good Daily we should have pineapple ;; fruits have various minerals.
Most of them are very tasty
```

**P.S.** : I tried `$` as well, but that was also not working.

Comment: is use of regex requirement here? Python string methods would be clearer and much easy in this case: search for 1st word in text, when found add everything to new list of words until encounter any from end-words or till data ends.

Comment: Yes actually regex is a requirement!!

Comment: then use as additional optional end \Z (same where now Apples, bananas and pinapples

Comment: Sorry didn't get you!! Can you please correct my regex and paste here or as an answer!! That will be helpful!!

Comment: should be like this, but could not test: p = r'(\bFruits\b\s*\w*\s*\n*.*?(\bApples?\b|\bbananas?\b|\bpineapples?\b|\Z))'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

include `\Z` in the expression as follows

```
text = '''Fruits are good

Daily we should have pineapple

In general, Fruits have various minerals.

Most of them are very tasty
'''

p = r'(\bFruits\b\s*\w*\s*\n*.*?(\bApples?\b|\bbananas?\b|\bpineapples?\b|\Z))'
sep = ";;"
lst = re.findall(p, text, re.I|re.M|re.DOTALL)
val = sep.join(str(v) for v in lst )
print(val)
```

output is as follows

`('Fruits are good\n\nDaily we should have pineapple', 'pineapple');;('Fruits have various minerals.\n\nMost of them are very tasty\n', '')
[Finished in 0.1s]`